npm install freezes when the process memory approaches 1GB
I have a react project. On different occasions, npm install fails (usually if there is no package-lock.json)
I have tried changing node and npm versions.
Today, I had an observation: The process freezes when the memory usage (as seen in process monitor) approaches 1GB.
I tried node --max-old-space-size=8000 $(which npm) install --verbose, also, export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192. None of these change the limit. The process stops when it gets "too close to 1GB".
Is there any other memory limit I can change? My system is Fedora 40 + KDE + Wayland, 32GB Ram. I'm using nvm to install node versions.

I'm still looking for an answer, but for anyone else having the same problem, I post my current workaround: (doing npm install inside docker)
docker run -it -v /path/to/your/project:/proj --entrypoint sh node:22
cd /proj
npm install
exit
# I'm back in my host machine, in my project folder
sudo chown ali:ali package-lock.json
chmod +x package-lock.json
npm ci

